# How do I fix my python script such that I receive my output in the matrix format?

Tags: python, for-loop, format

I am new to python and trying to format this output.

My code:

```
r1 = 1
r2 = 2
r3 = 3
r4 = 4
r5 = 5
for a in ['Interest rate','1%','2%','3%','4%','5%']:
    print (a)

for b in ['Rule of 72 Doubling time in years',72/r1,72/r2,72/r3,72/r4,72/r5]:
    print(b)

for c in ['Actual Doubling time in years','70','36','24','18','15']:
    print(c)
```

However the above code does not print in the matrix type format I desire:

Output I desire:

```
Interest Rate  Rule of 72     Actual doubling time
1%              72             70
2%              36             36
```

How do I change my code or add that I print it as above?

Comment: Try [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module, and see if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you a bit on the way:

```
r1 = 1
r2 = 2
r3 = 3
r4 = 4
r5 = 5

c1 = [a for a in ['Interest rate','1%','2%','3%','4%','5%']]
c2 = [b for b in ['Rule of 72 Doubling time in years', 72 / r1, 72 / r2, 72 / r3, 72 / r4, 72 / r5] ]
c3 = [c for c in ['Actual Doubling time in years', '70', '36', '24', '18', '15'] ]

for a,b,c in zip(c1,c2,c3):
    print(a,b,c)
```

This yields:

```
Interest rate Rule of 72 Doubling time in years Actual Doubling time in years
1% 72.0 70
2% 36.0 36
3% 24.0 24
4% 18.0 18
5% 14.4 15
```

Comment: Could also add string formatting to print more nicely with `print('{: <20} {: <40} {: < 40}'.format(a, b, c))`.

Comment: This gives a valueerror 
ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier

Comment: @user9991165 if you're getting this error trying to do the formatting it's probably because of the numeric elements in the second list. Try: `format(a, str(b), c)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools` to solve your problem.

Code:

```
import itertools
r1 = 1
r2 = 2
r3 = 3
r4 = 4
r5 = 5
list_1 = ['Interest rate','1%','2%','3%','4%','5%']
list_2 = ['Rule of 72 Doubling time in years',72/r1,72/r2,72/r3,72/r4,72/r5]
list_3 = ['Actual Doubling time in years','70','36','24','18','15']

for a, b, c in itertools.izip(x, y, z):
    print a,b,c
```

Output:

```
Interest rate Rule of 72 Doubling time in years Actual Doubling time in years
1% 72 70
2% 36 36
3% 24 24
4% 18 18
5% 14 15
```

Ideally, the above approach would solve your problem but what if you want to print it in a better way then you could use below-given approach.

```
import itertools
r1 = 1
r2 = 2
r3 = 3
r4 = 4
r5 = 5
list_1 = ['Interest rate','1%','2%','3%','4%','5%']
list_2 = ['Rule of 72 Doubling time in years',72/r1,72/r2,72/r3,72/r4,72/r5]
list_3 = ['Actual Doubling time in years','70','36','24','18','15']

for a, b, c in itertools.izip(x, y, z):
    print "%-10s  %20s  %30s" % (a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
Interest rate  Rule of 72 Doubling time in years   Actual Doubling time in years
1%                            72                              70
2%                            36                              36
3%                            24                              24
4%                            18                              18
5%                            14                              15
```

Hope this answers your question!!!

Comment: I receive an error AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'izip'. sorry if this is a rookie question. I am new to python

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? In Python 3, the builtin function zip behaves like itertools.izip does in Python 2.
My code is written  in Python 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this answer hopefully it will helps you.

Try to use a dictionary :

```
r1,r2,r3,r4,r5 = 1,2,3,4,5
import pandas as pd
my_dict = { 'Interest rate' : ['1%','2%','3%','4%','5%'],
            'Rule of 72 Doubling time in years' : [72/r1,72/r2,72/r3,72/r4,72/r5],
             'Actual Doubling time in years' : ['70','36','24','18','15']}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df
```

with pandas, you will have as the desired output matrix